# looking for data to develop machine learning algorithm for ranking

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I am looking for data to develop ranking algorithm e.g.: let's say we have horse racing data, we have horses data(height, weight etc.) and their places in races against other horses - goal is to create ranking of these horses (assumption is that this data is from short period of time and horses parameters didn't changed too much during this period)

of course it don't have to be horse-related data but you know the idea I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rank movies from the [movielens](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/) open dataset based on artificially generated user data.

**Dataset Summary**

MovieLens data sets were collected by the GroupLens Research Project
at the University of Minnesota.

This data set consists of:

- 100,000 ratings (1-5) from 943 users on 1682 movies.
- Each user has rated at least 20 movies.
- Simple demographic info for the users (age, gender, occupation, zip)

The data was collected through the MovieLens web site
(movielens.umn.edu) during the seven-month period from September 19th,
1997 through April 22nd, 1998. This data has been cleaned up - users
who had less than 20 ratings or did not have complete demographic
information was removed from this data set.

For code, reference steps are available on [Github](https://github.com/mottalrd/learning-to-rank) in a Jupyter notebook format.